# How to correctly convert a bit key to string for aes 256 encrytion?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, aes, cryptojs, pbkdf2

I am using CryptoJS AES 256 encryption:

```
CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(string, secret);
```

The secret is generated through:

```js
function generateKey(str) {
  const salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128 / 8);
  const key512Bits = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(str, salt, {
    keySize: 512 / 32,
    iterations: 100000
  });

  return key512Bits.toString(<-- base64 or hex -->);
}
```

But it seems like the returned secret string doesn't contain any special character if hex or only '/,+' and wierd ending '==' if base64

Is there any way to make the string much more unpredictable?

Thanks!

Comment: AES does not use 512 bit keys, only 128, 192 or 256 bit keys. Keys must be passed in CryptoJS as `WordArray`s and not as strings (otherwise the input is interpreted as password), i.e. you must not pass `key256Bits.toString(<-- base64 or hex -->)` but `key256Bits` in `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt()/decrypt()` for AES-256. The salt provides the randomness. The encoding does not matter for this, since the raw (and not the encoded) key is consumed.

Comment: so to get the 256 bits key should i just change 512/32 to 256/32? and also is it possible that i can parse key string to wordarray?

Comment: I've just tried to put the whole object of key256Bits to CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", key256Bits) and it gave an error TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.

Seems like it only accepts string key?

Comment: To answer the original question: 
You confuse *encodings* with *pass-phrases*. The 'unpredictable' string you are looking for is the key parameter - it is the pass-phrase. The pass-phrase is converted into a real key, which is always an array of bytes.  In order to represent an array of bytes in a readable form you choose an encoding, e.g. Hex .

Comment: Thanks for all the information
As now I know someone with an encoding string of iv and key can be converted to the real key and iv hence he/she can decrypt the real data without knowing the the pass-phrase. So does it matter to keep those encoding strings secure along with the pass-phrase?

Comment: In the case of need to store readable encoding key and iv string?